# Can't install the latest JDK

Tags: java, java-8

Somehow I need to use a old computer to run java, but every time I tried to install jdk it's popup with this message:

> Error:Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error:A fatal
>   exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Maybe my CPU is too old to run the latest jdk? My CPU is i3-2120

Comment: i3 is not too old

Comment: What exactly are you trying? We need some more information what your steps are.

Comment: as Christian said and we also need to know what your OS is